# Flask app: Heroku Postgres cannot load remembered user from db

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku

I have a simple Flask app on Heroku with '/login' route that is very standard (pretty much copied from famous Flask Mega Tutorial) and login form with ‘remember me’ functionality.

Occasionally, I get the following server error when loading the app (error log is large, but the end is):

```
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614460+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown) terminating connection due to administrator command
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614460+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614460+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614462+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".username AS user_username, "user".email AS user_email, "user".password_hash AS user_password_hash
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614462+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM "user"
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614463+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE "user".id = %(param_1)s]
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614463+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'param_1': 1}]
2020-05-25T18:01:05.614621+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I believe the problem is that I have a logged in user that is 'remembered'. When loading the app next time, the app logs in 'remembered' user but sometimes drops the connection with the database (hence OperationaError above). The error is solved by simply loading the page once or twice again.

The link http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8 has the explanation that this is something outside of the control of the programmer. I do not have the skills to prevent this type of error, but I could at least detect it and reroute the user for better user experience.

**Where in the typical Flask code could I check for this problem and instead of the user seeing ugly standard 'internal server error', reroute the user to my custom error page?**

Normal entry point for a user is '/index' that does not require login but has this check to see if the user is logged in:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
```

Here is the beginning of my ‘/login’ route code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the remember me functionality to check if it works without it?

Comment: Hi @Patch, sorry if the post wasn't clear. The app works 95% of time with or without 'remember me', but sometimes it gives the above message. So it seems it drops the db connection sometimes. Error only happens with 'remember me' enabled. I prefer not to remove that functionality. I think it is very useful for users.

Comment: It can't work randomly you need to check when it works and when it doesn't. Maybe try debugging your program when the error arrives. It can't just randomly drop the connection with the db it doesn't work like that. And the error happened in the `\login` route?

Comment: According to the sqlalchemy documentation this can happen - this is a quote from sqlalchemy documentation relating to this type of error: "Exception raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs ..."

Comment: The question is are you sure it's that? Because it looks like you have a simple program running and it looks like if it does happen it's like 1 in a million maybe your db setup isn't correct?. It never happened to me I can say that. Why is your current.is_autenticated is a problem? Should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem above. Flask has a inbuilt errorhandler decorator that will catch this error and render a custom error template:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

Please see details in the Flask Mega-Tutorial, [error handling](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling) section.